# How to create a bi-directional linked list and do not use pointer in ADT?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-declaration

Now I am trying to define an ADT and use it to create a linked list, and I want to let it fit the function `List newList(void);`. I know what should I do if it's like `List* newList(void);`. If I am trying to do fit `List* newList(void);`, then I will define this ADT like

```c
typedef struct List{
    struct List *next;
    struct List *prev;
    int number;
} List;
```

But If I define in this way, the nodes in linked list will be all pointers, which I don't want to use. Now I try to define linked list in the way below.

```c
typedef struct List{
    struct List next;
    struct List prev;
    int number;
} List;
```

But I received the error message:

```
List.h:4:17: error: field ‘next’ has incomplete type
    4 |     struct List next;
      |                 ^~~~
List.h:5:17: error: field ‘prev’ has incomplete type
    5 |     struct List prev;
      |                 ^~~~
```

I tried to move `typedef` into .c file (now it's in header file), but it still not work. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You can't avoid using pointers for this. Otherwise, you have a List which contains two Lists, each of which contains two Lists, and there's no end of the recursion.

Comment: It is impossible to create a linked-list without pointers, that's the key element of a linked-list. Don't use `typedef`.

Comment: You seem to have a major misunderstanding.  When you define the `next` and `prev` members of `struct List` as pointers, that does not mean that the nodes are pointers.  Linked list nodes do not contain other nodes as members, they contain *links* to other nodes.  And in C, such links manifest as pointers.  The nodes are the pointed-to objects, which are altogether separate and distinct from any pointers to those.

Comment: @Neil Although the usual is to use pointers, linked lists _can_ be created using _indexes_ into a single array instead of pointers. Also, why _not_ use `typedef`? OP's usage here [1st example] is fine.

Comment: @CraigEstey, I am on board with "don't use `typedef`" as a general (but not absolute) code style rule.  You are quite right, however, that the OP's use of `typedef` is not erroneous and does not contribute to the issue at hand.

Comment: @JohnBollinger As a matter of style, IMO, `typedef` is more fundamental than `struct`. If we teach basics of C, we have `char`, `short`, `int`, etc. as types. But, we also teach (e.g) `read` relatively early. So, if we _don't_ talk about `typedef`, how do we explain that the third arg to `read` is `size_t count`?

Comment: @CraigEstey using indices you still have to use pointer arithmetic. I suppose I should have said, "the first example would be simpler without the typedef." It's kind of a matter of style, but has real implications for the typedef namespace, (which, I agree, is OT.)

Comment: @CraigEstey, one does not need to teach `typedef` to introduce `size_t` any more than one needs to teach dairy farming to introduce milk.  But whenever we *do* explain `typedef`, it is not inconsistent to simultaneously recommend that its use be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But If I define in this way, the nodes in linked list will be all
> pointers, which I don't want to use

You are mistaken. All nodes in the list will have the type `struct List`. But they will be allocated dynamically.

As for this function

```
List newList(void);
```

then it just does not make a sense.

You need to declare the function like

```
List * newList( int number );
```

For example

```
List * newList( int number )
{
    List *node = malloc( sizeof( List ) );

    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = NULL;
        node->number = number;
    }

    return node;
}
```

If you do not want to allocate nodes dynamically when you can use for example the approach when a list is defined as an array. In this case you can add nodes to the list using the function

```
List newList( int number )
{
    List node = { .next = NULL, .prev = NULL, .number = number };
    return node;
}
```

But in this case you need to declare one more structure that indeed will describe a list. Your current structure in fact declares just a node of a list.

Comment: Although linked list nodes typically are allocated dynamically, as described, that is not an essential characteristic.